# Is it possible to write .nvimrc for NeoVim in Lua?

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

Is it possible to write .nvimrc for NeoVim in Lua? Is it planned for the future?

Comment: According to [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/31vxk1/configuring_neovim_without_vimscript/) on reddit I would say that you'll still have to write your `nvimrc` in vimscript. But maybe someone has more info than I have.

Comment: I'd even argue you don't _want_ to write your .nvimrc in Lua.  Ultimately, I think the plan is to use Vimscript for configuration and Lua for plugins, scripting, etc.

Comment: These days you can use the [vimpeccable plugin](https://github.com/svermeulen/vimpeccable) for this

Answer (score 2):

As of of June 2015, the lua to VimsSript transpiler integration is still being worked on, so currently you cannot use Lua to write `.nvimrc`, unfortunately.

See this issue: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1536

Comment: I believe what NeoVim wants to achieve is a VimScript to Lua transpiler, so they can use the LuaJIT runtime. So I'm wondering if the Lua engine is already integrated anywhere...